# TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

The following code is supposed to take strings from cat.txt and print the results on a file called cat_results.txt

```
def aln_count(aln_file):

                     .......................

    aln_file=open(aln_file,'r')
    lines=aln_file.readlines()

                     .......................

    with open(aln_file[:-4]+'_results.txt') as aln_r:
        aln_results = [line.rstrip() for line in aln_r]

    for seq in sequences:
        for i in range(3,len(lines)-1):
            if seq in lines[i]:
                result.append(lines[i+1])
        F=result.count('F')    
        aln_results.write('')
        aln_results.write(seq)
        aln_results.write('F: '+str(F)+' ')

    aln_r.close()
    result_file.close()

aln_count('cat.txt')
```

The error message I get is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-f603fc5d22c0> in <module>()
     32     result_file.close()
     33 
---> 34 aln_count('cat.txt')

<ipython-input-21-f603fc5d22c0> in aln_count(aln_file)
     10             sequences.append(line[0:4])
     11 
---> 12     with open(aln_file[:-4]+'_results.txt') as aln_r:
     13         aln_results = [line.rstrip() for line in aln_r]
     14 

TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: variables are cheap, why do you keep using the same one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently overwrite the `aln_file` variable in your code, so that it now represents a file object, in the line `aln_file=open(aln_file,'r')`.

When you later try to access it in `with open(aln_file[:-4]+'_results.txt') as aln_r`, you are now trying to slice the file object and not the original input passed to the function, which will throw the error.

Change the variable name, and this error should be corrected:

```
aln_file_object = open(aln_file, 'r')
lines = aln_file_object.readlines()
```